# Setting a certain spot in a randomly generated gridlayout to a certain type everytime

Tags: java, swing, layout, graphics

I have a java GUI panel with a gridlayout with a bunch of circles in each space. The size of the board and the color of each circle is randomly generated every time the board is made. How would I set the circle at bottom left space in the gridlayout to a certain color every time the board is generated? 4 is the type that  that space needs to be.

```
public GameBoard() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        for(int x = 0; x<row; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y<column; y++){
                arrayName[x][y] = new BoardSquare(1, x, y, color);
                arrayName[7][0] = new BoardSquare(4, x, y, color);
                add(arrayName[x][y]);
            }
        }
    setOpaque(true);    
}
```

Comment: you want it in a fixed or random position?

Comment: I want that fixed position to be the color black all the time

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: ill add it now, i forgot to before

Comment: You need to know the index position of the component based on the `(rowCount * columnCount) + column`

Comment: The bottom/left corner will be position `(7 * 7)`, but in your case, it's probably just as easy to place an `if` statement in your inner loop to check the `row` and `column` position